# ubuntu not query my local dns

Tags: networking, dns

I've a Windows Domain Controller, 192.168.1.1 with DNS service. Let's name it *dc.mydomain.local* .

I mapped *mypc.mydomain.local* to 192.168.1.2 and registered in DNS.

In my client's network card I've 192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.254, 8.8.8.8 configured as DNS. The */etc/hosts* has no entry for mydomain.local pc.

If I want to reach *mypc.mydomain.local* from a client, for example by ping or browser, it works fine.

Sometimes I get a name not found error. On my client, if I do the command

```
nslookup mypc.mydomain.local
nslookup dc.mydomain.local
```

I get nothing. If I do

```
nslookup mypc.mydomain.local 192.168.1.1
```

it resolve my query in 192.168.1.2

So there isn't a DNS problem.

If I reboot my client's network card, then i reach mypc.mydomain.local.

What is the problem?

Comment: Can you please check it is in the /etc/hosts file.

Comment: @PrinceKumarBarnwal it was on this file, but I removed it because I started to use a DNS. When I have these problem I cannot query nothing in *.mydomain.local. I add it to description ;)

Comment: Try to flush the dns cache

Comment: @PrinceKumarBarnwal I disconnect and reconnect the card, i suppose that this procedure flush dns cache. But why I need to do this? Why my client stop to check my dns (and only this DNS)?